# ActiveMQ Artemis: How to troubleshoot blocked acceptor?

Tags: activemq-artemis

We occasionally experience blocked Artemis (v2.19.1) TLS acceptors. *Blocked* means that a client can establish a TCP connection but no further data exchange occurs. The TLS handshake never starts. No helpful information in the Artemis logs. The only workaround currently is to restart Artemis.

Affected is the acceptor `artemis-tls` only. The acceptors `stomp-tls` and `mqtt-tls` continue to work, but do not have any load.

This is our acceptor configuration:

```xml
    <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://127.0.0.1:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;connectionsAllowed=10000;connectionsAllowed=10000</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="artemis-tls">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/certs/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=${keyStorePassword};enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="stomp-tls">tcp://0.0.0.0:61612?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/certs/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=${keyStorePassword};enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3</acceptor>
      <acceptor name="mqtt-tls">tcp://0.0.0.0:8883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/certs/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=${keyStorePassword};enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3</acceptor>
    </acceptors>
```

And here’s the log config:

```ini
    # Root logger level
    logger.level=INFO

    # ActiveMQ Artemis logger levels
    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.level=INFO
    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal.level=INFO
    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.level=INFO

    # if you have issues with CriticalAnalyzer, setting this as TRACE would give you extra troubleshooting information.
    # but do not use it regularly as it would incur in some extra CPU usage for this diagnostic.
    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.level=INFO

    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.level=INFO
    logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap.level=INFO
    logger.org.eclipse.jetty.level=WARN
```

Any hint on how to get more information on what is going on with the Acceptor is highly appreciated. Unfortunately, there is nothing helpful in the [docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html).

Comment: Did you try setting up java SSL debug ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I am not a Java developer …

Comment: -Djavax.net.debug=all or maybe some more concise option  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake on your startup command line

Comment: Any feedback here? Were you able to identify the problem?

Comment: Nothing helpful so far. The options -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake did not yield any output when the acceptor is stuck. tcpdump also revealed little: TCP three-way handshake completed, the client sends its TLS client hello, that’s it. No log messages from the kernel output about exceeding administrative limits or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis delegates low-level TCP work to Netty which in turn delegates to the JVM and ultimately to the operating system. There's no logging in the broker to get these low-level details.

This sounds like some kind of environmental issue. I would recommend using the SSL debug logging provided by the JVM as @ehsavoie suggested in the comments. For example, set this on the broker's command-line:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

You can do this by editing `artemis.profile` in the broker instance's `etc` directory. You can find more details about this logging [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug).

You might also try a packet capture (e.g. via tcpdump, WireShark, etc.) to see exactly what is happening on a TCP level.

Answer (score 0):

Metrics indicating a blocked thread in Artemis and a closer look at it pointed us in the right direction: The acceptor was blocked by our custom login module, which by itself was blocked by a REST call to an external system. We have now introduced some safeguarding against external influences. Looks like we are stable again.

Addendum: Stack traces, see comments from @JustinBertram

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you happen to grab a thread dump which demonstrates the blocked thread. Also, I would have expected any JAAS login module to be invoked after the TCP connection was established which would also occur after the TLS handshake was successful. Are you saying that the TLS handshake never completed when the login module was blocked?

Comment: @JustinBertram, yes, we have seen the (one!) thread blocked in the Artemis console (but did not additionally involve any Java tooling). Also, the TLS handshake was never completed: The client sends its TLS Hello message, but _never_ receives any response from the broker (all documented in the tcpdump). I was not only expecting the TLS handshake to complete but also some CORE/Openwire protocol messages before handing over to the JAAS login module. Is there only one thread accepting new connections?

Comment: Could you paste the stack-trace for the stuck thread somewhere and link it here? The broker uses Netty but nothing should be blocking the event loop. It sounds like this may be happening in this case (which would be a bug) which is why I'm interested in getting more details.

Comment: Oh, false memories about one blocked thread; it was more than one. The screenshots added above are the only pieces that I have left. Does it help?

Comment: It helps a bit. Unfortunately I can't see the root of the stack-trace for thread `80` to confirm it's not blocking the event loop. However, its name (i.e. `Thread-0 (activemq-netty-threads)`) indicates it was created from a thread-pool owned by the event loop so I think it's safe to say that the event loop isn't blocked. Also, given the other method calls in the stack-trace I don't see how it's possible that the TCP connection and the TLS handshake haven't completed by that point. That part seems really bizarre.